# What does "A Gossip Girl in Sweet Valley with traveling pants" mean?

Tags: phrases, american-english, metaphors, cinema

In the 2010 film *Easy A*, there is an exchange between several characters:

> Rhiannon: *Aren't you supposed to be like, eternally in love with him,
>   and shit?*
>
> Olive Penderghast: *Yes, I believe so. If I was "A Gossip Girl in Sweet
>   Valley with traveling pants"*.

What does Olive mean here by "Yes, I believe so. If I was "A Gossip Girl
in Sweet Valley with traveling pants".?

Please note: English is not my native language, so the simpler and clearer you can make your explanation, the better.

Comment: It's just referring to some other tv shows and movies that were made for women that have central themes of love and romance

Comment: Nice Luis, glad you came back. Olive is making fun of the way Rihanni is using language here. She's saying "*Eternally in love with him and shit*" is shallow and trite; phrased in a way a stereotypical airheaded teenaged girl might say it. Googling "valley girl" or looking that topic up in Wikipedia might also shed some light.

Comment: [Gossip Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397442/), [Sweet Valley High](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108949/), and [The Sisterhood of the Travelling Pants](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0403508/)

Comment: It's not really a language issue, these are cultural references.

Comment: barmar just answer the question

Answer (score 1):

As your comments will indicate, this is an instance of referential humor dealing with various instances of young adult fiction dealing with teenage girls. The joke is that the character uttering them wants to differentiate herself from the themes contained therein, specifically an idealized portrayal of romance.